# How do i go to the next screen by selecting item (just tapping on the item) from spinner in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to get a screen transition when i select a value from the spinner. My spinner has just 2 values. The 1st one is selected by default. What I want is that when i click on the 2nd value in my spinner, it should take me to the new screen.

Please Help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your problem is solved then accept correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use onItemSelectedListener of your Spinner. Here is a Demo,

```
public class AndroidSpinner extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

 TextView selection;
 Spinner spin;
 String[] items = { "bangladesh", "bangla", "bd", "australia", "japan",
   "china", "indiaA", "indiaC" };

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


  Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
  setContentView(spin);

  spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

  ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

  spin.setAdapter(aa);
 }

 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
   long id) {
  // Do your Stuff Here
   Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

 }

 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  selection.setText("");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for open new activity or new screen onitemselected event of spinner.

```
public class SpinnerExample extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener { 

    String[] items = { "Dipak", "Aadi", "Bharat", "Pratik", "Usha", "Jayesh", "Deep", "Imran" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner mSpn1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mSpn1);
        mSpn1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        mSpn1.setAdapter(adpt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do your Stuff Here
        // For Open New Activity
        Intent mInNewAccount = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(mInNewAccount);
        finish();

        // For Open New Screen
        setContentView(R.layout.second_screen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to set up the spinner adapter and everything, simply add the code to go to the next screen when the other item is selected on the spinner.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{
  if(position ==0)
         //do nothing (assuming that you would want to stay in the same screen)
  else if (position ==1)
     {
         //go to the next screen, probably by using an INTENT to the next activity or using setContentView(theLayoutXmlFile)
     }
 }
```